# Asymptotic bounds: $\ll$ vs. $\ll_{\epsilon}$?

Tags: asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

I am feeling a bit slow today. In Analytic Number Theory it is usual to express asymptotic bounds by specifying the relation of the constant to a specific variable, i.e.

$\log n \ll_\epsilon n^\epsilon$

which means that $\log n \leqslant C_\epsilon n^\epsilon$ for sufficiently large $n$, where the constant $C_\epsilon$ depends only on the constant $\epsilon$.

Could someone explain what are the benefits of this versus just using the usual $\ll$.

I understand that $f \ll_\epsilon g \Rightarrow f \ll g$? Is it equivalent or is it a stronger statement?

Thanks!

Comment: I think it's just a matter of clarity. Especially when there are a lot of parameters involved, it's nice to know which parameter a constant depends on.

Comment: I guess you are right and I think the discussion in this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10202/is-it-legitimate-to-write-nested-big-os-in-an-asymptotic-formula-for-a-multivari) answers my question pretty much.